# Laravel Filament Table Actions: url() not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-filament

I'm using Filament to create a table. I have the following two functions in my Livewire class. The getTableRecordUrlUsing() function works as expected.

The getTableActions() function spawns an error page saying **"Missing required parameter for [Route: recipe.show] [URI: recipe/{id}] [Missing parameter: id]."**

```
    protected function getTableActions()
    {
        return [
            Action::make('edit')
                ->url(fn (Recipe $r): string => route('recipe.show', ['id' => $r])),
        ];
    }

    protected function getTableRecordUrlUsing()
    {
        return function (Recipe $r) {
            return route('recipe.show', ['id' => $r]);
        };
    }
```

One function works. The other doesn't. I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do not change closure parameter names in filament, try to rename **$r** to **$record** :

```
protected function getTableActions()
{
    return [
        Action::make('edit')
            ->url(fn (Recipe $record): string => route('recipe.show', ['id' => $record])),
    ];
}

...
```

Update: This will be no longer a problem in v3.